# Why is my heavy python script pausing on windows? Can it be prevented?

Tags: python, windows, concurrent-programming

There is a python script I built called `convert.py`, which is a file converter (SQLite3 -> SQLite3). It takes about 30 minutes to finish, working on with heavy CPU and I/O.

I opened 30 CMD.EXE windows on my computer (Windows 7, CPU with 2 cores and hyper-threading), and started `convert.py` on each  window. I let them work over night, so I expected that it will be all done until next morning ... but it didn't. Only half of them were done. The CPU monitor log told me that my computer was working 100% on it for 1 hour and suddenly it started to use only 25%. It seems that all CPU power wasn't used for the left tasks.

The left tasks resumed it work when I pressed Ctrl+C on it.

So, what is going on? Is this problem a python's problem, or windows' problem? Is there a way to let my computer work constantly 100% on my python script until all of them are done?

Comment: Are these processes all working on the same database?

Comment: Either as Steven has said, all those processes are working on the same database and there's some sort of conflict (most probable case), or it's just that after some time your processes needded so much memory that they had to use the 'swap'(and maybe even exhausted the swap, who knows).

Comment: With heavy CPU and IO and 2 cores it's unlikely that you have any use of running more than 4 at once. Put them into batch files instead.

Comment: I'm inclined to vote down, as there's no real question asked here: My script is slow, I don't know why, help!  And, you don't show the script, or any info on what else is running at the same time.

Python, in of itself, is single threaded. It also has the GILOC - Global Interpreter LOCk. That is, it can only execute one interpreted instruction at a time. Unless you're dealing with threaded native modules, you'll never see a 100% utilization from python on an multiple core/CPU system.

Comment: I'm so sorry that my reply was so late. I also should apologize that I  can't show the script here. I additionaly found out that the python script suddenly stops to work hard when there are other processes working hard in the same computer. It was the first time I've heard about GILOC, do you mean about GILOC is that python script can't use multiple CPUs, even if there are multiple processes running concurrently?

Comment: @NathanErnst: It is spelled: `GIL`, not `GILOC`. It has nothing to do with the OPs question. `GIL` doesn't prevent multiple Python processes to use multiple CPUs in parallel. Please, [read this](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf) to avoid spreading FUD.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that each process used massive memory, and I tried to work it concurrently. It was over capacity. It was frequently *swapping out*, but it was hidden by SQLite access which was also working hard with my HDD.

I would like to thank Lennart, who notified me to check other params in my computer, and everybody who gave me guesses and hints, since I gave too less information about the issues occuring in front of me.